# Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found - maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: java, maven

Issue: The following problem occurs when I compile my project w/ maven (note: I'm working on windows):

> Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project XYZ:  Fatal error compiling: tools.jar
>   not found: C:\java\jdk1.8.0_40..\lib\tools.jar -> [Help 1]

Error occurs from both command line and eclipse (Eclipse STS) - mvn clean; mvn install

Notes:

- System env variable, JAVA_HOME, was set to C:\java\jdk1.8.0_40
- C:\java\jdk1.8.0_40\lib\tools.jar is there
- Tried clearing local maven repo (.m2) - error still occurred
- configured maven compiler plugin to point to C:/java/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/javac.exe executable with source=target=1.7 - same error
- Tried installing java 1.7.0_75 in eclipse and using that (but maven is still used for the compile -- right-click on project, run as, maven install): same error (even with maven compiler's plugin configuration's executable set to C:/java/jdk1.7.0_75/bin/javac.exe)

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue? I am facing similar problem.

Comment: Did you know you can accept your own answer?

Answer (score 9):

Issue resolved:
Setting System env variable, JAVA_HOME, to Java JDK 1.7 fixed the problem.

I tried jdk1.7.0_45 and jdk1.7.0_75 - they both worked.

Notes:

- I thought setting the compiler executable for the compiler plugin in 
  pom.xml would mean that the executable was used in all cases;
  apparently it's not - the JAVA_HOME variable overrode it in this
  case.
- Some other folks had issues b/c their JAVA_HOME was set to a
  JRE    instead of a JDK.  My JAVA_HOME for Java 1.8 was set to JDK
  1.8, but    I still received the same error.

Comment: Thank you! I had defined JAVA_HOME in the System/Windows environment variables and it did not help. I ended up creating the JAVA_HOME within eclipse (Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Classpath variables) - this new JAVA_HOME now pointed to JDK 1.7 and it worked :-)

Answer (score 5):

I also faced similar issue when building the project in eclipse ( sts version)
I figured out the issue was because I had jre installed in 2 locations and I jre configured in the eclipse was pointing to the pure jre folder.
So just check that your jre is pointing to the jre folder inside the jdk not any other jre as the tools.jar is in jdk/lib

Answer (score 2):

Even after configuring Eclipse to use a **JDK** from **Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JRES**, you may still get errors when you try to perform a **Maven build**.

In this case make sure that the **JRE tab in Maven Build** is configured correctly.

Go to **Run -> Run Configurations**, open the **Maven Build** category and do one of the following:

1. Make sure that the **Workspace default JRE** is selected and it points to a JDK.
2. In the **Alternate JRE** menu, select a configured JDK.

[image: Run Configurations screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If tools.jar is not found, try adding it up in your project's dependencies on eclipse.

Firstly, copy the location of tools.jar which would look something like this
***C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.x.x\lib***

Then, on eclipse, Right click your project and go to 
***Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries***

Click on **ADD External JARs** button.

Paste the link you have copied above on File Name link bar and click OK button.

Now, tools.jar should be listed on Libraries.

Click okay to close the window.

Now, run the Maven install.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if Eclipse is pointing to a JDK and Not a JRE.
For that :
Window ==> Preferences ==> Java ==> Installed JRES ==> Add button ==> Standard VM and add your JDK path .

Answer (score 0):

When I added the JDK to the Libraries the problem was solved. The issue is like tools.jar is not found as part of the jre distribution

Comment: can you share more details for make more understanding.

Comment: Yes please.  I've downloaded the JDK and I still can't get this to work.  Mind you, I'm not using Eclipse or maven.  I'm trying to run ant.

Comment: Normally JRE might be added as library. One need to use JDK to use tools.jar

Answer (score 0):

Make sure if Eclipse is pointing to a JDK and Not a JRE. For that : Window ==> Preferences ==> Java ==> Installed JRES ==> Add button ==> Standard VM and add your JDK path .
This worked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this will help or not, I had a  similar type of issue:

`Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project XYZ: Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: C:\java\jre1.8.0_271..\lib\tools.jar -> [Help 1].`

So I searched for tools.jar in jdk/lib and found it. I copied it from jdk lib to jre lib folder.
I restarted my sts and it worked fine.

Comment: Copying tools.jar from jdk to jre may let go of the compilation issue, but that should be a bad idea, given that the very reason for importing it can fail. More appropriate action would be to point to the jdk itself.